# PHP can you convert unicode from within a string

Tags: php, unicode

I have a php string with the following

```
$string="Br\xFCtal"
```

Is it possible to convert the \xFC part to the correct special character?

I know this works

```
$string="\xFC";
echo utf8_encode($string);
```

but I don't know if it can be done as part of a string with other characters.

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem? https://3v4l.org/1SQAQ

Comment: Sorry I don't think I have the right info, so the string/variable is in json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the encoded string is a literal encoding in JSON string, you could replace '\x' to unicode format '\u00'.

```php
$string = '"Br\xFCtal"';
echo json_decode(str_replace('\x', '\u00', $string));
```

Output:

```
Brütal
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.